# How to assign a piece of javascript code to a variable and display it in textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

So far I have tried a code, which is a assigning a piece of javascript code and displaying it into  with id="myCodeArea". But its not displaying in proper format as I am using JSON.stringify for converting the code in JSON I want code in original form. Can anyone help how to achieve it?

```js
var chart =  {      
      title:{
        text: "Books Issued from Central Library"
      },
      axisY :{
        includeZero: false
      },
      axisX: {
        valueFormatString: "MMM",
        interval: 1,
        intervalType: "month"
      },
      data: [
      {        
        type: "spline",  
        indexLabelFontColor: "orangered",      
        dataPoints: [
        { x: new Date(2012, 00, 1), y: 1352 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 01, 1), y: 1514,  indexLabel: "Exams" },
        { x: new Date(2012, 02, 1), y: 1321 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 03, 1), y: 1163 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 04, 1), y: 950 , indexLabel: "Holiday Season"},
        { x: new Date(2012, 05, 1), y: 1201 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 06, 1), y: 1186 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 07, 1), y: 1281, indexLabel: "New Session" },
        { x: new Date(2012, 08, 1), y: 1438 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 09, 1), y: 1305 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 10, 1), y: 1480, indexLabel: "Terms" },
        { x: new Date(2012, 11, 1), y: 1391 }        
        ]
      }
      ]
    };
 var xyz = document.getElementById("myCodeArea");
 xyz.textContent = JSON.stringify(chart);
```

```html
<div id="myTextArea">
      <textarea id ="myCodeArea" cols="100"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: What format are you expecting this to display in?

Comment: You cannot get the original code unless you parse the script tag your code was found in; or you could wrap the value in a function, convert the function to string and then parse that. In particular, `new Date(...)` will have evaluated and then been converted to String form, so it is unrecoverable from JSON. If you're happy with JSON (as opposed to code) and just want the indentation, use the third argument to `stringify`.

Comment: Same format as chart object

Comment: I don't want date as string format , I want `new Date(2012, 00, 1)` I want that object as it is

Comment: Its more like , u can see a code in blogs where u can edit

Comment: @ashishraaj But the content of `chart` does not have a format! The value of the date has already been calculated by the time the chart gets put into the textarea. Same if you had something simple like `2+2`, this would result in `4` being put in. If you want a specific text to appear in the textarea, use that text! That is, as a string literal.

Comment: So tell me how to achieve i, i got ur pointt. I tried to make chart variable as string but without parsing I can't do it. Is there any way, I would be pleased to know

Comment: I just want to achieve this dynamically without doing hard coding

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a way for you to do the editing (stripped your data items a little) ...

```js
var chart =  {      
      title:{
        text: "Books Issued from Central Library"
      },
      axisY :{
        includeZero: false
      },
      axisX: {
        valueFormatString: "MMM",
        interval: 1,
        intervalType: "month"
      },
      data: [
      {        
        type: "spline",  
        indexLabelFontColor: "orangered",      
        dataPoints: [
        { x: "2012-00-01", y: 1352 },
        { x: "2012-01-01", y: 1514,  indexLabel: "Exams" },
        { x: "2012-02-01", y: 1321 }
        ]
      }
      ]
    };
 var xyz = document.getElementById("myCodeArea");
 xyz.textContent = JSON.stringify(chart);
```

```html
<div id="myTextArea">
    <textarea id ="myCodeArea" cols="100"></textarea>
</div>
```

...  and then when you execute the chart object through your method you do the date parsing something like this:

```
var some_var = new Date(chart.data[i].dataPoints.x);
```

If you still need to embed the function itself, here is one way how to embed functions in a string

```
// function name and parameters to pass
var fnstring = "runMe";
var fnparams = [1, 2, 3];

// find object
var fn = window[fnstring];

// is object a function?
if (typeof fn === "function") fn.apply(null, fnparams);
```

Src: http://www.sitepoint.com/call-javascript-function-string-without-using-eval/

Answer (score 0):

I changed code `xyz.textContent = JSON.stringify(chart, null, 4);`
Here 4 is number of spaces you want.
Hope you are expecting this.

```js
var chart =  {      
      title:{
        text: "Books Issued from Central Library"
      },
      axisY :{
        includeZero: false
      },
      axisX: {
        valueFormatString: "MMM",
        interval: 1,
        intervalType: "month"
      },
      data: [
      {        
        type: "spline",  
        indexLabelFontColor: "orangered",      
        dataPoints: [
        { x: new Date(2012, 00, 1), y: 1352 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 01, 1), y: 1514,  indexLabel: "Exams" },
        { x: new Date(2012, 02, 1), y: 1321 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 03, 1), y: 1163 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 04, 1), y: 950 , indexLabel: "Holiday Season"},
        { x: new Date(2012, 05, 1), y: 1201 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 06, 1), y: 1186 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 07, 1), y: 1281, indexLabel: "New Session" },
        { x: new Date(2012, 08, 1), y: 1438 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 09, 1), y: 1305 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 10, 1), y: 1480, indexLabel: "Terms" },
        { x: new Date(2012, 11, 1), y: 1391 }        
        ]
      }
      ]
    };
 var xyz = document.getElementById("myCodeArea");
 xyz.textContent = JSON.stringify(chart, null, 4);
```

```html
<div id="myTextArea">
      <textarea id ="myCodeArea" cols="100"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Its very helpful but here I need the key values unquoted, and date in same format `new Date(2012, 00, 1)` . that's the code not the string or json. Thanks AR_Web

Comment: @ashishraaj Then you have to put json as a string. If you use as a variable and executing JSON function then it will definitely evaluated